# String is not translated android

Tags: android, xml, string

When I tried to open my android project in eclipse a few minutes ago I got these errors telling me the the strings in the strings.xml file are not translated to other languages (this morning everything was good).

I found something online that said I should change MissingTraslation to Warning instead of Error, but it didn't help.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

it's shown by the Lint tool.

just change its settings (to warning/info/... instead of error), and run Lint again (the button on the toolbar, near the button of launching the app, looks like a checkbox with a "V" in it, looks similar to [**this one**](http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1321373282606/tips/lint/lint-toolbar.png) ).

Comment: it can be shown on both. just please run the lint tool again and you shall see it being changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings

juste put translatable="false.

Best regards,
Yassine